# Plot binary dataframe using column-numbers as yaxis and row-numbers as xaxis in R

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have a 2D dataframe consisting only of 0s and 1s.
Similar to this:

> data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*10, 1, p=0.5), nrow = 10))

I want to plot this by having the row number on the x-axis and the column number on the y-axis, such that that each position in the plot is filled with a colour with respect to its value (e.g. red for 0 and blue for 1).

Instead of looking at a dataframe like this:

> data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*10, 1, p=0.5), nrow = 10))
> 1   0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
> 2   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
> 3   0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
> 4   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
> 5   0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
> 6   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
> 7   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
> 8   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
> 9   1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
> 10  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0

I would like to have a plot with 0s in one colour and 1s in another colour.

Many thanks for your help!! :D

Comment: `heatmap(as.matrix(your_data))`. You can search for "heatmap in r" to find more examples and options - some other packages provide a lot of flexibility.